# How can i access the same Stack in two different Classes?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack

I have two different methods, where threads are started. Now I want the first run() method to add elements on this stack and the second run() method to pop elements from the same Stack. How can I access the same Stack in two different classes?
Should I add and remove the elements in the run() methods or in the method where the Threads are running?

The run method creats Objects i want to add to the Stack.

This is part of the code for the Threads in my Main Class:

```
public static void startProducers(int producerCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < producerCount; i++ ) {
        Thread counter = new Thread(new Producer(i));
        counter.start();
    }

}

public static void startUsers(int UserCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < UserCount; i++ ) {
        Thread counter1 = new Thread(new User(i));
        counter1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I create a Thread for every User and Producer, because every single Thread should produce/remove Objects in the run method. The Stack contains objects beeing produced in the producers run method. Can you give an example how to use mStack as a member field?

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the same stack object in both the Thread Class. Something like this

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {
    Thread1(Stack s) {}
    method run() {// push in the same stack object}
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {
    Threa2(Stack s) {}
    method run() {// pop from the same stack object}
}
```

If you can elaborate more about the code you have written by adding some sample, It would be of great help!!
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I editet the Code above. I dont know how to access the same Stack in tow different run methods, so I can push and pop objects from the Stack.

Comment: If I use the Stack inside my Thread methods, how can i get the Object which is produced in my producers run method?

Comment: If the above two methods are in the same class and its easy to do that. Just add a new field in that class (stack) and access it.